# Getting a specific text from a website using Regex in Shortcuts

Tags: html, ios, regex, shortcut

I’m trying to create a Shortcut on iOS that uses Regex, what I’m trying to accomplish is getting the price of a product from a website but no matter what Regex commands I use don’t work. It would be easier if my computer was up and running and I was able to use addons to view the site better but I’m stuck on iOS for the time being. Viewing the source code line 606 displays

'productPrice':'409.99',

But nothing I try pulls the the price even from different lines in the code.

I’m trying to get the price from https://www.microcenter.com/product/512484/intel-core-i7-9700k-coffee-lake-36-ghz-lga-1151-boxed-processor

I just can’t figure out how to retrieve the price being shown, I’ve tried so many combinations I had to turn to more experienced user help.

Comment: It seems shortcuts isn’t pulling the source code from site but it seems like it’s rich text or a simplified breadkdown of the site. This is where I got the idea from, it’s a shortcut that pulls a definition from dictionary.com/browse/  example he’s using as Regex http://imgur.com/ag6d8NQ

Answer (score 0):

this works for me: `'productPrice':'(.*?)',`  - [link](https://regex101.com/r/G7jSCk/1)

Make sure you are getting the part of the page source that contains this information.

Comment: Let me give this a try.

Comment: It didn’t work, I’m going to need to find something more specific when I use the “Get Contents of URL” set as GET, it should be pulling the source code but it isn’t. I’m using the same method as another Shortcut user who made a dictionary.com/browse/ that pulls the definition from the site. This is a portion of his method of Regex.  http://imgur.com/ag6d8NQ

Answer (score 0):

The answer was so simple, if using shortcuts on iOS I was able to pull the price of the MicroCenter product by these commands.

```
URL - microcenter page to product
Get Contents of URL (leave as is)
Get Text from Input
Match Text - Pattern - \$......
Get item from list - Item at Index / 2  (2 is for items on sale or not)
```

The rest you can decide what to do with it, make a notification or whatever you decide how to display the price. This answer I found was a way to make sure it works. Now I’ll make a menu of multiple items from micro I have my eye on to pull all the prices in 1 click display. https://m.imgur.com/Iljvsx6